# Listview is not scrolling vertically?

Tags: java, android, listview

I have one Parent Fragment which is holding view pager.

In view pager there are two fragment called 1stFragVP and 2ndFragVP.

In 1stFragVP's layout i have Listview.

View pager is able to scroll horizontally but listview vertical scroll is not happening.

Parent Fragment XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/parent_ll"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_weight="5">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp">


            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                style="@style/CustomTabLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="#f1f1f2"
                app:elevation="0dp"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/orange"
                app:tabMode="fixed" />


        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

1st FragVP XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:divider="#ebf2f2"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"/>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/no_item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/no_item_txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/medium_font" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post your code xml java file etc

Comment: @Ahamed please check question again.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
yourlistView.setOnTouchListener(new ListView.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    int action = event.getAction();
                    switch (action) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            events.
                            v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                            break;

                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            events.
                             v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                            break;
                    }


                    v.onTouchEvent(event);
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

it will disable the parent view touch management and pass the event to your `listview`.

Comment: I am trying this code but i am not getting events. How do i get that?

Comment: The touch event is attached to your listview..do u have any other layout in front of that